# custom methods and the usefulness of constructors and prototype in web-dev

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

ok so i know that prototype is used for inheritance and when coupled with a constructor function can be used to make custom methods. so my question here is two fold: how do i make methods for pre-built JavaScript objects like integers,strings,arrays,etc...

the other question is besides making my own methods what is the usefulness of constructors/prototype in everyday web development(i.e. creating websites) or is this more so for high-end development like making a web app or developing with new tech(i.e. html5 canvas or three.js) i haven't seen an example anywhere on the web of this being used in an everyday situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a Javascript method to an already existing object, you can simple add it to its constructor's prototype:

```
String.prototype.firstLetter = function() { return this.charAt(0); }
var myStr = "Cool str!";
alert(myStr.firstLetter()); // 'C'
```

As for how useful it will be, depends on what you do with Javascript. If you write client-side  code and you need to modify an existing component, monkey-patching a function may be useful there. If you need some structure on your code (and you do), creating an object to represent the interface state may be useful.

Also, knowing how to use a tool usually avoids self-harm. =)

If you are interested, you may want to take a look into Crockford's [page](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) or buy his Javascript: The Good Parts book.

There is a lot of confusion you can avoid if you get to know the language, and you may even get to like it and find out you can do a lot of useful stuff in it.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but what do you mean by "interface state"

Comment: Usually javascript (web) changes the User Interface, keeping track of what is what, and where it is in any given time, what may prove to be rather complex. Creating a structured code based on OOP may help avoid many issues found in that process.

Answer (score 1):

You can add functions into a class's prototype:

```
String.prototype.report_fish = function() { alert("a fish!"); };
"".report_fish();
```

You can do this with numbers as well, although the syntax to invoke is slightly different:

```
Number.prototype.report_fish = function() { alert("a fish!"); };
(0).report_fish();
```

As to why you'd do this, I personally believe that you should avoid doing this to built-in objects where possible. (A persistent problem to work around when building re-usable Javascript libraries used to be and probably still is people's tendency to override and extend the `Object` prototype.)

Comment: Primitives are boxed and treated as objects when you invoke function properties on them. `(Number.prototype.foo = 'bar', (5).foo)` evaluates to "bar".

Comment: Ah, neat. It's the bracketing syntax I was missing.

Comment: `5 .foo` also works (note the space). This could probably confuse some minifiers though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that extends Number:

```
Number.prototype.between = function(a, b) {
  return this >= a && this <= b
}
var num = 0;
if (num.between(0,0)) alert('is between')
else alert('not');
```

Although I often use the prototype, I have not yet run across a good reason to use the constuctor property, which returns the type of an Object. W3schools.com has a good illustration of this property at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_constructor_math.asp